# div center of parent div width,height 0px

Tags: html, css

i have create one html file with div element in other parent div

```
<div class="note-idea" >
    <div class="idea-content"></div>
    <div class="idea-circle"></div>
    <div class="idea-child"></div>
</div>
```

and css file

```
.note-idea {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.idea-content{
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

i want make idea-content on center off note-idea with css and note-idea have width 1px,height 1px.
but it false

Comment: i do not fully understand your question

Comment: Your want the container `note-idea` to have a width and height of `1px`?

Comment: What is the actual behavior you're seeing?

Comment: 'not-idea` is a parent of all those `div` then how it can have 1x1 px dimension. even are you able to see that 1x1 px div ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note-idea cannot be 1px by 1px, you should read up on how divs work. However, this will center idea-content in note-idea:

```
<div class="note-idea" >
    <div class="idea-content"></div>
    <div class="idea-circle"></div>
    <div class="idea-child"></div>
</div>

and css file

.note-idea {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.idea-content{
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```